# For each client, get in every row, a column containing first purchase date

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

I am using Power BI (I can use only DAX).

Starting from this table:

| Client | Purchase Date |
| --- | --- |
| ClientA | 01/01/2023 |
| ClientA | 01/02/2023 |
| ClientB | 01/03/2023 |
| ClientB | 01/02/2023 |

I would like to create a new column, called First Purchase Date that, for each client, keeps first purchase date, like:

| Client | Purchase Date | First Purchase Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client A | 01/01/2023 | 01/01/2023 |
| Client A | 01/02/2023 | 01/01/2023 |
| Client B | 01/03/2023 | 01/02/2023 |
| Client B | 01/02/2023 | 01/02/2023 |

How can I solve it using only DAX?

I tried to create

```
First Purchase Date = MINX(VALUES(Table1[Client]),MIN(Table2[Purchase Date]))
```

But it's like Third column is equal to second:

| Client | Purchase Date | First Purchase Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client A | 01/01/2023 | 01/01/2023 |
| Client A | 01/02/2023 | 01/02/2023 |
| Client B | 01/03/2023 | 01/03/2023 |
| Client B | 01/02/2023 | 01/02/2023 |

Comment: Is Customer a separate dimension? (Normally it would be). Then you can just create a column in the Customer table: MINX(RELATED('Sales'),[Purchase Date])

Answer (score 0):

`REMOVEFILTERS` to remove the row context.

Try:

```
First Purchase Date =
  CALCULATE(
    MIN(Table2[Purchase Date]),
    REMOVEFILTERS(Table2[Purchase Date])
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below DAX for **New Column**-

```
First Purchase Date = 
CALCULATE(
    MIN(your_table_name[Purchase Date]),
    ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name, your_table_name[Client])
)
```